# ContainerVIew not equal to ScrollView

Tags: swift, scrollview

Please help me. I can understand why `containerView` smaller than `ScrollView`.

```
private let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
    let scrollView = UIScrollView()
    scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    scrollView.clipsToBounds = true
    return scrollView
}()

private let contentView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.clipsToBounds = false
    return view
}()


scrollView.delegate = self
scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
scrollView.alwaysBounceVertical = true
view.addSubview(scrollView)
scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
scrollView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.top.equalTo(topStackView.snp.bottom)
    make.leading.equalTo(view.snp.leading)
    make.trailing.equalTo(view.snp.trailing)
    make.bottom.equalTo(view.snp.bottom)
}

contentView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.top.equalTo(scrollView.snp.top)
    make.leading.equalTo(scrollView.snp.leading)
    make.trailing.equalTo(scrollView.snp.trailing)
    make.bottom.equalTo(scrollView.snp.bottom)
}
```

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

My `containerView` is smaller then `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set a `width` to your `contentView`.

```
make.width.equalTo(scrollView.snp.width)
```

This could happen because the scrollView don't set width for inner views.

Comment: U r great! Thank you! Maybe you can tell me how to place in UIButton.titleLabel text at center? textAligment = .center fix it to Ycenteranchor, but Xanchor is fixed to left side. I've tried to get titleLabel.textXanchor, but this is only {get} property... I can't resolve this issue... =(

Comment: You're welcome!
About the button, the titleLabel is set on center by default, if I'm not wrong. Send me how you are creating the button or just open another question and send me the link here on comments.